# How to add class to element when element gets stuck in place via position: sticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky, dom-events

I want to use native `position: sticky;` and add a class to the element if it gets stuck in place (when its position changes to "fixed") and change its style (eg. reducing font color, etc.). I guess there is no css attribute that would work as an indicator for that, so it hast to be done JS.

Is there an event that gets fired or a different way to test this except using a polyfill and its logic?

Thank you for every hint!

Comment: Good question, I don't think there's a event  firing. You'd have to monitor the margin difference until such time as it reaches the value in the CSS and fire a function then. That being the case you might as well have to do the whole thing in JS.

Comment: That said, support is **awful** - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: You can monitor all css changes using mutation observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver